# Centering a couple of divs together horizontal

Tags: css

Hello i wondered how i would be able to center divs together horizontal, so far i've used margin: 0 auto; to put them in the middle, but the divs go right under each other instead of next to each other. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdMmPo

HTML:

```
<section id="rating-box">
   <div class="rating"></div>
   <div class="rating"></div>
   <div class="rating"></div>
   <div class="rating"></div>
   <div class="rating"></div>
   <div class="rating"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#rating-box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}


#rating-box .rating {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #7a7a7a;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As you see they are on top of each other, i would like to know how to make them stand next to each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` to child elements and `text-align: center` to parent:

```css
#rating-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#rating-box .rating {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #7a7a7a;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="rating-box">
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
  <div class="rating"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Athax Glad that I helped you :)

Comment: I will give you best answer, as soon as it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

You can just float them.

```
#rating-box .rating {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Won't help, they loose their centration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#rating-box .rating {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #7a7a7a;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more detail to your answer.

Comment: Add more details for answer you provided